# django powered website switches between logged in users

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I am trying to find the root cause for the following problem with a Django powered website. The problem is:

Sporadically, a user that is currently logged into the website, on clicking random links on the website, is automatically switched to a different user along with the permissions of that user. 
It is not clear yet in which scenario this happens. Visiting different pages on the website may bring him back to his login.

Django version: 1.9.4

Webserver: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu 12.04)

Database: mysql 5.5.4

Python: 2.7.3

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Template caching is enabled:

```
loaders = [('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
]),
]
```

This website uses `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` in the templates. The user variable is set only once, and it is when the user logs in. LDAP Backend for authentication

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

function is run, and then

```
login(self.request, user)
return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

I read various blog posts about how Django does session handling. But I do not understand how refreshing/clicking around random links can switch the current user to a different one.

If somebody knows what could be going wrong in this scenario, please reply. I hope I have given the required information to explain the problem, and the environment.

The LoginView:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.views import generic
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .forms import LoginForm

User = get_user_model()


class LoginView(generic.FormView):
form_class = LoginForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
template_name = 'accounts/login.html'

def form_valid(self, form):
    username = form.cleaned_data['username']
    password = form.cleaned_data['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(self.request, user)
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)


class LogoutView(generic.RedirectView):
url = reverse_lazy('home')

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    logout(request)
    return super(LogoutView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I do not see the `User` from `User = get_user_model()` used anywhere in the app. I did a recursive grep, just in case this detail is important.

Comment: Why `self.request` and not only `request` ? Can you show full code for auth and login ? The problem is only there not in settings

Comment: Thanks. Added the code.

Comment: Are you OK with trying a full example that works ? https://coderwall.com/p/sll1kw/django-auth-class-based-views-login-and-logout (check latest comment for a change)

Comment: I saw something similar once and the issue came from accidentally using the same cache between development/testing and production. So if you are using redis or memcache, make sure you have different ones for each stage

Comment: @Saksow: Thank you! The problem is, this is visible only in an environment I am currently now allowed to touch. My local setup on the laptop is not helping me reproduce the problem. So, yes, as I reproduce this problem on my local setup, I can use a full example. Much appreciated.

Comment: In production, there are many processes running Django, and in general different requests, even from the same machine, will be served by different processes. The problem could be that different processes assume you are a different user, but this should not happen. What is your session backend?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides, session backend is mysql database.

Comment: Are you using a cache? Are you caching whole pages?

Comment: Hmm. Like I wrote in the question, the template caching is enabled(loaders). I hope that's an answer to your question. The only time we initialize the `user` is when `LoginView` is executed. The subsequent requests just rely on the `sessionid` that was sent part of the request to verify if the user has logged in. However, printing the username in the profile page, checking the user's group access rights is all done in a template, and it is verified using `user.is_authenticated` etc. Hence, I also doubt that caching could be the culprit. Hope this additional info is useful. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, and reading, I figured that the problem with incorrect usage of `cache_page`. 
`cache_page` along with `vary_on_headers` is the right way to avoid the problem I have seen.